# magento mod rewrite not working help wanted(htaccess) :)

Tags: .htaccess, magento

my situation.....

i have this url http://www.example.com/index.php/category?catid=3

i want to have this rewritten to

http://www.example.com/bikes/3

my rewrites on the website are enabled....so i have nice urls on the website for the products

the pages i want to be rewritten are my own modules for pages with text

i have put this in my htaccess

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^bikes/(\.*)/$ category?catid=$1
```

i have tried about any thing like 1000 combinations but nothing seem to work also i checked if my htaccess is working but it does.First line works also redirect to google works.

Hope someone is able to tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand, if you type in the "nice" URL directly does the correct page show? Are you asking how to get Magento to create the "nice" URLs instead of the "ugly" URLs?

Answer (score 0):

I had this example around here, and I think you can work it out to your needs:

Pretty URL: /topic-41/favourite-cheese.html
Ugly URL: /viewtopic.php?t=41
.htaccess:

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^topic-([0-9]+)/[A-Z0-9_-]+.html$ /viewtopic.php?t=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: sorry still dont get it...clean you explain it more clearly to me...i think magento might be different....do you use magento?

Comment: this sucks was really hoping some could help me with this...hhmm :(

Comment: Sorry, i'll adapt it to your needs, and post it as soon as possible. must give a try here, because mod_rewrite is not my favourite thing :D